How to fix AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'generator_llm' with Ragas in python?
I have a code using the package ragas that works in a notebook but doesn't work in a script. I am trying to have it as a script. The error is inside the package, so I have no idea how to fix it. The version of the package is the same in the script and notebook '0.1.4'
import importlib.resources
import os

import pandas as pd
import yaml
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import Blob
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PDFPlumberLoader
from langchain_experimental.text_splitter import SemanticChunker
from langchain_openai.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from ragas.testset.evolutions import multi_context, reasoning, simple
from ragas.testset.generator import TestsetGenerator
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

load_dotenv()


def get_pdf_files(collection_name, filegroup_name):
    """Get the pdf files from the collection and filegroup from the ds-librairie-genai-provisioning"""

    collections_path = importlib.resources.files("genai_provisioning").joinpath(
        "collections"
    )
    collection_path = collections_path.joinpath(collection_name)

    filegroups_path = collection_path.joinpath("filegroups")
    files_directory = filegroups_path.joinpath(filegroup_name).joinpath("files")

    pdf_files = list(files_directory.glob("*.pdf"))

    return pdf_files


def combine_all_page(docs):
    """Combine all pages from one PDF into one Document object"""
    try:
        page_content = "/n".join([doc.page_content for doc in docs])
        page_metadata = docs[0].metadata
        if "page" in page_metadata:
            page_metadata.pop("page")
        return [Document(page_content=page_content, metadata=page_metadata)]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def generate_testset(configs_file):
    """Generate RAGAS synthetic test set"""
    with open(configs_file) as f:
        configs = yaml.safe_load(f)

    collection_name = configs["collection_name"]
    filegroup_name = configs["filegroup_name"]
    version = configs["version"]

    files = get_pdf_files(collection_name, filegroup_name)
    print(f"Number of files: {len(files)}")

    docs = []
    for file in tqdm(files):
        doc_ = PDFPlumberLoader(
            str(file),
            text_kwargs={
                "x_tolerance": configs["x_tolerance"],
                "y_tolerance": configs["y_tolerance"],
            },
        ).load()
        doc_ = combine_all_page(doc_)
        docs.extend(doc_)
    print(f"Number of documents: {len(docs)}")

    for doc_ in docs:
        doc_.metadata["filename"] = doc_.metadata["source"]

    splitted_testset_docs = docs

    # RAGAS to generate a synthetic testset
    generator = TestsetGenerator.with_openai()

    testset = generator.generate_with_langchain_docs(
        splitted_testset_docs,
        test_size=configs["test_size"],
        with_debugging_logs=True,
        distributions=configs["distributions"],
    )

The error is
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 3
      1 from generate_testset import generate_testset
----> 3 generate_testset("generate-testset.yml")

File ~/github_repos/ds-research-genai/common/src/rag_pipeline_evaluator/generate_testset.py:86, in generate_testset(configs_file)
     83 print("len(splitted_testset_docs)", len(splitted_testset_docs))
     84 print("splitted_testset_docs[0]", splitted_testset_docs[0])
---> 86 testset = generator.generate_with_langchain_docs(
     87     splitted_testset_docs,
     88     test_size=configs["test_size"],
     89     with_debugging_logs=True,
     90     distributions=configs["distributions"],
     91 )
     93 # Remove nan and short ground truth
     94 testset_improved = testset

File ~/github_repos/ds-research-genai/common/src/rag_pipeline_evaluator/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ragas/testset/generator.py:179, in TestsetGenerator.generate_with_langchain_docs(self, documents, test_size, distributions, with_debugging_logs, is_async, raise_exceptions, run_config)
    174 # chunk documents and add to docstore
    175 self.docstore.add_documents(
    176     [Document.from_langchain_document(doc) for doc in documents]
    177 )
--> 179 return self.generate(
    180     test_size=test_size,
    181     distributions=distributions,
    182     with_debugging_logs=with_debugging_logs,
    183     is_async=is_async,
    184     raise_exceptions=raise_exceptions,
    185     run_config=run_config,
    186 )

File ~/github_repos/ds-research-genai/common/src/rag_pipeline_evaluator/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ragas/testset/generator.py:227, in TestsetGenerator.generate(self, test_size, distributions, with_debugging_logs, is_async, raise_exceptions, run_config)
    225 # init filters and evolutions
    226 for evolution in distributions:
--> 227     self.init_evolution(evolution)
    228     evolution.init(is_async=is_async, run_config=run_config)
    230 if with_debugging_logs:

File ~/github_repos/ds-research-genai/common/src/rag_pipeline_evaluator/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ragas/testset/generator.py:189, in TestsetGenerator.init_evolution(self, evolution)
    188 def init_evolution(self, evolution: Evolution) -> None:
--> 189     if evolution.generator_llm is None:
    190         evolution.generator_llm = self.generator_llm
    191         if evolution.docstore is None:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'generator_llm'

It does the generating till 100%, then fails.
In a notebook, the exact same code with the exact same arguments work.
evolution is inside the package and I do not touch it directly. I have no idea why it would be a string rather than the correct object.
The error happens both if I call the scrip inside a notebook after importing it or in a terminal. But the same code in a notebook is ok.

Seems to me like your configs["distributions"] is being parsed as str ( which make sense ), can you attach the .env ?
also, can you make sure to generate Evolution instances instead of just passing it as read from .env ?

My .env is
LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2=true
LANGCHAIN_ENDPOINT="https://api.smith.langchain.com"
LANGCHAIN_API_KEY=...
LANGCHAIN_PROJECT="rag-evaluation"
OPENAI_API_KEY=...
The keys have values, but I don't think I should share them online

configs["distributions"] is parsed as a dict. I checked it with this print(isinstance(configs["distributions"], dict))

I don't know what you mean by this "can you make sure to generate Evolution instances instead of just passing it as read from .env". Can you elaborate?
I do not explicitly create or read any object called evolution in my own code. My understanding is that it's something internal to TestsetGenerator.with_openai()

since you are not specifying distributions in your config,  as you can see in the source code here: https://github.com/explodinggradients/ragas/blob/v0.1.4/src/ragas/testset/generator.py
distributions is a dict where keys are from from ragas.testset.evolutions and values are floats.
I am just not sure where configs["distributions"] is coming from.
can you print it and send output ?
